# Loop Through Array With Node.JS and EJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make a todo app with Node.js using EJS as a templating engine. All the objects are in 3 arrays: subject, date, and detail. They are in the arrays.

I am using this code in the express route:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
      var subjects = [];
      var duedates = [];
      var details = [];
      var ids = [];

      var userId = 'some user provided value';
      var sql = 'SELECT * FROM assignments WHERE owner = "' + req.user.email + '"';
      connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;

        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

          subjects.push(results[i]['subject']);
          duedates.push(results[i]['duedate']);
          details.push(results[i]['details']);
          ids.push(results[i]['id']);

          console.log(details)

          //res.render('dashboard',{username:req.user.email, subject: subjects, date: duedates, detail: details, id: ids});
        } // ...
      });
    });
```

And this code on the EJS template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pencil and Pens</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Pencil and Pens</h1>
        <h2>Welcome:
            <%= username %>
        </h2>
        <form action="/addassignment" method="post">
            Subject: <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"> Due Date: <input type="duedate" name="duedate"> Details:
            <input type="details" name="details">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Assignment...">
        </form>
        <br />
        <div id="assignmentbody">
            <% for(var i=0; i < subject.length; i++) { %>
                <%= subject[i] %> |
                    <%= date[i] %> |
                        <%= detail[i] %>
                            <form style="display:inline-block;" action="/deleteAssignment" method="post">
                                <% } %>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Only the first entry is displaying even though there is 3 in the array.

Thanks so much!

Ben Fein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your code I see that the 3 arrays **subjects**, **duedates** and **details** names are different I mean you are missing the **'s'** for all the 3 arrays while displaying inside **for**loop. Add these. It will work fine.